# adding a popup during a mouseover event for a dynamically generated table

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

Relatively new to javascript and jquery and I have a couple of questions on event listeners in jquery.

So I have an HTML form that dynamically generates a table.

The objective is to create an event such that when I hover over a certain cell, a popup will appear next to it.

I tried this:

HTML - The tag the JS is connected to

```
let td_inter = document.createElement('td')
td_inter.innerHTML = "test"           
td_inter.classList = 'popover'
td_inter.setAttribute('data-html', 'test')
td_inter.setAttribute('data-position',"bottom left")
td_inter.setAttribute('data-variation',"very wide")
```

JS

```
$(document).on("mouseover", 'td.popover', function() {
    $('td.popover')
    .popup({
        on: 'hover',
    });
})
```

The reason why I tried this is that I have a previous static `div` above with the following code that worked.

HTML - The tag the JS is connected to

```
  <div class='thirteen wide field'>
       <div class='desc' id='test_desc' data-html="" data-position="bottom left" data-variation="very wide">
            <label for="test">test label</label>
        </div>
  </div>
```

JS

```
$('div.desc')
.popup({
    on: 'hover',
});
```

I realize I needed to use the `.on` to make it work for the dynamically generated table, but it seems not to be working. The event seems to work when I hover (I tried just to console.log) but I cant get the popup to show. Do I have to place it in a div?

additional background:
I am using semantic ui if that helps. 
I also included these resources if this helps:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To all those interested, I had to restructure my dynamic table to generate it into something like this:

HTML:

```
<table class="ui table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="one wide">Key</th>
         <th class="two wide">Value</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="popover">
         <td>1</td>
         <td>Foo</td>
      </tr>
      <div class="ui popup mini transition hidden">Foo Longer</div>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.popover', function() {
  $(this)
  .popup({
         popup: $('div.popup'),
         inline:true,
          on:'hover',
          position: 'right center',
          lastResort: 'right center',
     }).popup('show');
});
```

`div.popup` is set to hidden and will become visible once the event is satisfied (`mouseover` in this case).

sample: https://jsfiddle.net/gr0e4cwt/11/

Answer (score 0):

can you just try below code in JS instead of using `document.mouseover`:

```
$('td.popover')
.popup({
    on: 'hover',
});
```

Comment: It doesnt not seem to be working. I tried making the ` class` the same, as well as making it a`div` inside the `td`. Both did not work.